# SQL - select where elements of a string match elements of another string

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a table field, let's call it `pattern` containing a list of comma separated values.
For example: '10,20,30,40,50'

I need to select * from said table, where at least one element from another similar string appears in that field too.

For example, say I have the string '10,50,70' A record whose `pattern` field is '10,20,30,50,70' should be selected, because 10 and 70 are present in '10,50,70'.`

Is there any way of doing this, except lots of OR where i check if `pattern` LIKE '%10%' OR `pattern` LIKE %50% OR `pattern` LIKE %70% ?

Comment: Read up on database normalization. This is bad practice, and every solution provided makes it worse.

Comment: I agree.  There is no reason to even try to answer this question, as it's a foundational feature of SQL to do this kind of activity.  Then you can `SELECT * FROM table where id in ("pattern")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) as an alternative like below though as already suggested in comment, consider Normalizing your table.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('10','10,20,30,50,70')
OR FIND_IN_SET('50','10,20,30,50,70')
OR FIND_IN_SET('70','10,20,30,50,70') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Patrick Hofman, normalising the database is the best solution.

If you really must stick with such a table layout then there are a couple of solutions.

You can split up the comma separated values and join the results based on that. Not that the cross joined tables are just generating a range of numbers (in this case 0 to 99), but this must equal or exceed the max number of delimited values. It will also be slow as no indexes can be used. Also large numbers of records are generated in memory to do this calculation.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub0.id, sub1.id
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pattern, ',', units.i + tens.i * 10), ',' -1) AS pattern_id
    FROM some_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) tens
) sub0
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(pattern, ',', units.i + tens.i * 10), ',' -1) AS pattern_id
    FROM some_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) tens
) sub1
ON sub0.pattern_id = sub1.pattern_id
AND sub0.id != sub1.id
```

If the comma separated value is the key to another table then you could maybe do a couple of joins based on FIND_IN_SET.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.*
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_patterns b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.patterns)
INNER JOIN some_table c
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, c.patterns)
```

In reality it would probably be best to normalise you database, possibly using SQL based on these solutions just to help you extract the data to your new normalised format

Answer (score 0):

I've inherited this method of storing small lists of integers and wrote the included function to rotate CSV of integers into a column.

```html
CREATE function [dbo].[udf_IntegerColumnFromCSV] ( @DelimStr nvarchar(max) )
 returns @ListOfInts table ( Value int )
AS
BEGIN
 set @DelimStr = @DelimStr + ',' -- add one more to the end
 declare @i int     -- the "start" of the next value to be read
 declare @j int     -- the location of the next comma
 declare @le int     -- line end
 set @i = 1 
 set @j = 1
 set @le = len(@DelimStr)
 while ( @j < @le ) begin
  set @j = charindex( ',', @DelimStr, @i ) -- find the end of the next row
  insert into @ListOfInts (Value) values ( cast(substring( @DelimStr, @i, @j-@i ) as integer) ) 
  set @i = @j + 1 
 end
 return 
end
```

In a situation where you have a list of values stored as CSV:

select ID, ValueList from TableX

ID :    ValueList

20 :    38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 61,62,63,64,65,66, 70,71,72

21 :    12

22 :    61,62,63,64,65,66

Use the function to pivot the values into a column:

select ID, vl.* from TableX cross apply dbo.udf_IntegerColumnFromCSV(ValueList) vl

20: 38

20: 39

20: 40

20: 41

20: 42

20: 44

20: 61

20: 62

20: 63

20: 64

20: 65

20: 66

20: 70

20: 71

20: 72

21: 12

22: 61

22: 62

22: 63

22: 64

22: 65

22: 66